# Start a java project which uses Jargon Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

We are trying to develop a java application for iRods(a middleware for Heterogeneous databases). To use the jargon API we need to use the Java Jargon API which is in this [link](https://github.com/DICE-UNC/jargon) . We are using Java for the first time and not aware of how to import the library in our project. 
In the [presentation](http://irods.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/api-and-interface-tutorials.pdf) the following steps are mentioned at the beginning

`git clone https://github.com/DICE-UNC/jargon.git`

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

But I want to expose those libraries in my new eclipse project. Any pointers regarding setting up those libraries for an exlipse project would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a quote of the Eclipse JDT docs. But I try to give you a hint on the matter.

When you have managed to install maven and got the build running, you will find a `jargon-xxx.jar` in your `target` folder.

Take that jar file and place it in your eclipse project and select "configure build path" - "add Jar". Select the jargon.jar file in your project folder, it is now on your classpath in the project.

Hint: If this is a professional project, you need to have someone on your team to setup a proper build environment for you, possibly using maven or some other tool that manages dependencies for you and is supported in your IDE. Otherwise you can only perform manual builds of your software, which will hinder your progress really soon. You should hire someone to guide you through the first steps and get you rolling.